# Background Image in Textbox Using CSS

Tags: html, css

Before posting it over here, I have done thorough research work on my question but I haven't found any suitable answer to it.

How do I post an background image in a textbox using CSS?

Am using IE11.

The below is the code which am using

```
<a href="#">
<div id="imagecontainer"></div>
<style>

#imagecontainer {   
  background-image: url("content\A.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

I have tried many possibilities to sort it out but am unable to. The box is going to be displayed but not the image in the backgorund in my code.

Can any of you suggest me whats wrong in it please.

Comment: "desktop\icons\A.png" LoL

Comment: Could you let me know what it should be

Comment: Not willing to help if someone actually proves he hasn't even learnt the absolute very basics and even lies about having done "thorough research" prior to asking. If your type of research earned the attribute "thorough", we'd still be living in caves.

Comment: try to find your image is there in the above mentioned path and you are not using textbox in your html code.. what you are trying to do.. explain clearly with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to reference a url in a different directory use the following:

```
#imagecontainer {   
background-image: url('Images/example.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-size: contain;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate the path specification please. Can't I copy the path location from the desktop? Do I need to copy and paste it in the XAMPP folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o4afu9wh/2/)**

```
input {
    padding: 9px;
    outline: 0;
    font: normal 13px/100% Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background: #FFFFFF url('http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/584_form/bg_form.png') left top repeat-x; /* make sure about the image path you mentioned is right */
}
```

And I didn't saw any textbox code in you HTML. As you mentioned, I showed simple example for textbox with background image. Hope this is what you want.